# How to use jsf to edit some data in a database

Tags: mysql, database, jsf

i have an app that displays some data entered in a databse, this should allow a user to delete or edit this information, so far i have managed to get it to delete, but i am wondering, what is the best method for editting the data, what i would like if possible is to click on an edit button on a page already populated with the data and this to take the user to a webpage that has only that selected records pre populating textboxs and then allow the user to edit these, how would i do this ?

this is how i am deleting a row from the database

```
                <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="u" value="#{userBean.getUserList()}"  
                             paginator="true" rows="10"  
                             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">  
                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            User ID
                        </f:facet>
                        #{u.userID}
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Name
                        </f:facet>
                        #{u.name}
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Email 
                        </f:facet>
                        #{u.email}
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Address
                        </f:facet>
                        #{u.address}
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Created Date
                        </f:facet>
                        #{u.created_date}
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Delete
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{user.delete(u.userID)}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Edit
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:commandButton value="Edit" action="{user.delete(u.userID)}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
```

and this is the backing bean allowing me to delete

```
 public void delete(long userID) {
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection con = null;
        if (userID != 0) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");
                String sql = "DELETE FROM user1 WHERE userId=" + userID;
                ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                int i = ps.executeUpdate();
                if (i > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Row deleted successfully");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    con.close();
                    ps.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Thanks

EDIT

i have figured out how to update the data, my question is now simply, how do i get the data from a row and populate a new page with input boxes with the selected data Or even better would be to edit the data live in the table, is this possilbe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of taking the user to a second page to edit the data, you can make use of primfaces DataTable - Row Editing see this

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowEditing.jsf

Answer (score 0):

send user object only with editdata method

```
<h:commandButton value="Edit" action="{user.editData(u)}" />
```

then you can use prepared statement with update like shown below

String sql = "UPDATE user1 set name = '"+name+"', email = '"+ email +"', address = '"+address+"'  WHERE userId=" + userID;

I will suggest try hibernate.